# Can I use Magento's rest API through JavaScript?

Tags: magento-1.9, api, app

I want to create Magento store Android app using PhoneGap. I found Magento's XML-RPC is the best option to create an API but now how I can call this API using only JavaScript and HTML ?

So it is sure my case I have to use JavaScript to use the API.So there is two options I think

1. If yes then how to use ?
2. if No then what's option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can**

you can call magento's xmlrpc apis using jQuery XML-RPC library.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.xmlrpc.js"></script>
```

first is simple jquery library and second library file you can get from here:

**http://jquery-xml-rpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html**

Here is two type of example of this call.

**1. Login Call**

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
    methodName: 'login',
    params: ['api_user', "api_key"],
    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('Sucsses');       
        Session = response[0]; // this session key is important for next transaction                 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(status);  
    }
});
```

**2. After Login Calls**

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
    methodName: 'call',
    params: [Session, 'Your_methode_name',[0,'any other parameter',1]],
    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('Sucsses');
        var data = response[0];  // Here is your data.
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('error-inside');
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I hide my username and password (api user and api key)? If it's javascript, can't people just view the js file/code in plaintext? Should I be worried?

Comment: [I asked a new question about the username and password, available here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902060/how-do-i-hide-secure-my-username-and-password-in-a-javascript-file?noredirect=1#comment70986364_41902060). I'm still not sure how I'm going to hide my api username and key.

Comment: If you are using only js then you can't. 
I think you can put this whole code on the server and call that.
Call that returns only session id so your credential on the server.