# XML_Connect with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ce-1.9.2.4, mage-xmlconnect

I'm creating a mobile app using the Ionic 2 framework. Can anybody please point me in the direction of getting started or some boilerplate code for using Magento's XML_Connect through Javascript?

I have searched but haven't come up with anything.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

I apologise if this question seems rather broad, but I honestly am drawing a blank with getting started with XML_Connect. As I am building a mobile app, my understanding is that XML_Connect is better to use than the SOAP or REST APIs, as it already provides all the necessary functions. At a very basic I need to learn how to:

1. Create a new session;
2. Login/Create a customer;
3. Pull in categories;
4. Render products from a category;
5. Render the Product detail (Simple and Configurable products);
6. Add products to a cart; and
7. Checkout

Additionally, as I'm building my app using the Ionic Framework, the only scripting language I'm able to use is Javascript.

I should add that I have already activated the module in Magento, have the new Mobile menu available, and have generated a new app code.

The article: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/ didn't help much.

Comment: Hi maGz, please refer this link for SOAP API of magento. here i the link: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a JQuery XML-RPC library you should have no troubles talking with Magento's API, see the answer below from an existing Q/A:

- [Can I use Magento's rest API through JavaScript?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116030/can-i-use-magentos-rest-api-through-javascript)

> **Yes, you can**
>
> you can call magento's xmlrpc apis using jQuery XML-RPC library.
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script src="js/jquery.xmlrpc.js"></script>
> ```
>
> first is simple jquery library and second library file you can get
>   from here:
>
> **http://jquery-xml-rpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html**
>
> Here is two type of example of this call.
>
> **1. Login Call**
>
> ```
> $.xmlrpc({
>     url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
>     methodName: 'login',
>     params: ['api_user', "api_key"],
>     success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
>         alert('Sucsses');       
>         Session = response[0]; // this session key is important for next transaction                 
>     },
>     error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
>         alert('error');
>         console.log(status);  
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> **2. After Login Calls**
>
> ```
> $.xmlrpc({
>     url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
>     methodName: 'call',
>     params: [Session, 'Your_methode_name',[0,'any other parameter',1]],
>     success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
>         alert('Sucsses');
>         var data = response[0];  // Here is your data.
>     },
>     error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
>         alert('error-inside');
>         console.log(error);
>     }
> });
> ```

If you are looking for a purely Javascript way:

- http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html

Or with Ionic as you mentioned:

- https://github.com/aaronksaunders/Ionic-NutritionSample
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-call-REST-APIs-in-ionic-framework

Comment: Hi Boomer. Thank u for your answer. It works really well. Unfortunately I've been quite ill the past few days, so haven't had a chance to se this answer until now. Is there any way to award the bounty seeing that it has expired?

Comment: @maGz I'm not sure other than talking to a moderator here, if its a big hassle no worries.  Hope you're feeling better!

Comment: @Boomer, let me enquire

Answer (score 0):

This Might be helpful. Please take a look.

[Magento XML Connect Demo](https://gist.github.com/fbrnc/bdade1df328c3f766a3c)

```
<?php
// Initialize
$app = new SimpleHttpClient('http://www.demo.local/xmlconnect/');
$app->addCookie('app_code', 'INSERT APP CODE HERE');
$app->addCookie('screen_size', '600x400');
// get products in category 3
echo "\n[REQUEST] Fetching product catalog...\n";
$response = $app->request('catalog/category/id/3/offset/0/count/100');
if ((string)$response->status == 'error') {
    echo "Error: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
    exit(1);
}
$productId = (int)$response->xpath('/category/products/item[1]/entity_id')[0];
// add this product to the cart
echo "\n[REQUEST] Adding product $productId to cart...\n";
$response = $app->request('cart/add/product/' . $productId);
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while adding product to cart";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
// get cart content and verify the item we just added is there
echo "\n[REQUEST] Fetching cart content...\n";
$cart = $app->request('cart');
if ((int)$cart->products->item[0]->entity_id != $productId) {
    echo "Could not find product in cart";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Verified that product is in cart now.\n";
// get billing address form fields
echo "\n[REQUEST] Getting billing address form fields...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/newBillingAddressForm');
foreach ($response->field as $field) {
    echo " - {$field['name']}\n";
}
$address = array(
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'street' => array('Street 1'),
    'city' => 'San Francisco',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region_id' => '12', // California
    'postcode' => '94015',
    'telephone' => '4152300694',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => ''
);
// billing address
echo "\n[REQUEST] Posting billing address...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/saveBillingAddress', 'POST', array('billing' => $address));
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while saving billing address";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
// shipping address
echo "\n[REQUEST] Posting shipping address...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/saveShippingAddress', 'POST', array('shipping' => $address));
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while saving shipping address";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
// get shipping methods
echo "\n[REQUEST] Fetching available shipping methods...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/shippingMethodsList');
$shippingMethods = array();
foreach ($response->method->rates->rate as $rate) {
    $shippingMethods[] = (string)$rate['code'];
    echo " - {$rate['code']}\n";
}
// save shipping method
echo "\n[REQUEST] Saving shipping method...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/saveShippingMethod', 'POST', array('shipping_method' => $shippingMethods[0]));
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while saving shipping method";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
// get payment methods
echo "\n[REQUEST] Fetching available payment methods...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/paymentMethodList');
$paymentMethods = array();
foreach ($response->method_list->method as $method) {
    $paymentMethods[] = (string)$method['code'];
    echo " - {$method['code']}\n";
}
if (!in_array('checkmo', $paymentMethods)) {
    echo "This demo only supports 'checkmo'. Please enable 'Check / Money Order' in configuration.";
}
// save payment method
echo "\n[REQUEST] Saving payment method...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/savePayment', 'POST', array('payment' => array('method' => 'checkmo')));
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while saving payment method";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
// order review
echo "\n[REQUEST] Fetching order review...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/orderReview');
echo "Products:\n";
foreach ($response->products->item as $item) {
    echo " - {$item->qty}x {$item->name}\n";
}
echo "Totals:\n";
foreach ($response->totals->children() as $total) {
    echo " - {$total->title}: {$total->formated_value}\n";
}
// place order
echo "\n[REQUEST] Place order...\n";
$response = $app->request('checkout/saveOrder', 'POST', array('payment' => array('method' => 'checkmo')));
if ((string)$response->status != 'success') {
    echo "Error while saving order";
    exit(1);
}
echo "Message: " . (string)$response->text . "\n";
echo "Order ID: " . (string)$response->order_id . "\n";
/**
 * Simple HTTP client for demonstration purposes
 *
 * @author Fabrizio Branca
 * @since 2015-05-21
 */
class SimpleHttpClient
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $cookieJar = array();
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl;
    /**
     * @var resource
     */
    protected $ch;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $baseUrl
     */
    public function __construct($baseUrl)
    {
        $this->baseUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/') . '/';
        $this->ch = curl_init();
    }
    /**
     * Request (and store cookies from response in cookie jar)
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return SimpleXMLElement response
     */
    public function request($url, $method = 'GET', array $data = array())
    {
        $url = ltrim($url, '/');
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->baseUrl . $url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $this->getCookieString());
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        }
        $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);
        $this->addCookiesToJarFromHeader($header);
        return simplexml_load_string($body);
    }
    /**
     * Add cookie
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function addCookie($name, $value)
    {
        $this->cookieJar[$name] = $value;
    }
    /**
     * Extract cookies from header and add them to the cookie jar
     *
     * @param string $header
     */
    protected function addCookiesToJarFromHeader($header)
    {
        preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $header, $matches);
        $cookies = array();
        foreach ($matches[1] as $item) {
            parse_str($item, $cookie);
            $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
        }
        $this->cookieJar = array_merge($this->cookieJar, $cookies);
    }
    /**
     * Return all cookies as a string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getCookieString()
    {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($this->cookieJar as $name => $value) {
            $tmp[] = "$name=$value";
        }
        return implode('; ', $tmp);
    }
    /**
     * Destruct
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bilal. Thank you, but I have seen this. However my issue is working with XmlConnect using Javascript.

Comment: I must be missing something as I am really struggling to interact with XMLConnect...even for something as simple as fetching product data from a specified category :(